# Makefile for automatically processing image files

Tags: image, makefile, make

I have a Makefile that is used to automatically process some image files. The basic idea behind this is

- copy everything from `col-noborder` and `col-rewnew` to `col`
- use ImageMagick `convert` to copy the files from `col-addborder` to `col` and add a pre-defined border
- use ImageMagick `convert` to copy the files from `col` to `bw` while applying a grayscale (greyscale?) filter

Due to the layout of the project, I have to apply this filter for five sets of identically structured subdirectories. Since the project contains quite a number of image files, I want to use parallel processing and update only the files whose sources have changed (hence the use of `make` in the first place).

The current implementation does what it is supposed to do, but it is quite ugly. It basically generates a secondary `Makefile.raster` based on the input files and then defers to the targets in that generated file. The generation of that file takes over 15 seconds alone, which leaves quite a bit of room for improvement.

I'm sure that there are various ways to improve this script. Can I get the same process (that is, including parallel processing and update-only) using a single, more dynamic Makefile? If not, can I somehow speed up the generation of the secondary Makefile? Is there anything else I should correct?

```
IMGPATH1 = content/part1/raster
IMGPATH2 = content/part2/raster
IMGPATH3 = content/part3/raster
IMGPATH4 = content/part4/raster
IMGPATH5 = content/part5/raster

IMGPATHS = $(IMGPATH1) $(IMGPATH2) $(IMGPATH3) $(IMGPATH4) $(IMGPATH5)

RASTERMAKEFILE = Makefile.raster
rastercoladdborderfiles := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /col-addborder/*, $(IMGPATHS)))
rastercolnoborderfiles := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /col-noborder/*, $(IMGPATHS)))
rastercolrenewfiles := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /col-renew/*, $(IMGPATHS)))
rastercolfiles := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /col/*, $(IMGPATHS)))
rasterbwfiles := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /col/*, $(IMGPATHS)))

rastermakefile: force 
    rm -f $(RASTERMAKEFILE)
    printf "all: allcolnoborder allcolrenew allcoladdborder allbw\n\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

    # copy /col-noborder/ to /col/
    for infile in $(rastercolnoborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-noborder/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile: $$infile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
        printf "\tcp $$infile $$outfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done; \
    printf "allcolnoborder: " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)
    for infile in $(rastercolnoborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-noborder/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    printf "\n\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

    # copy /col-renew/ to /col/ 
    for infile in $(rastercolrenewfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-renew/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile: $$infile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
        printf "\tcp $$infile $$outfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    printf "allcolrenew: " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)
    for infile in $(rastercolrenewfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-renew/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    printf "\n\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

    # add border to images in /col-addborder/, copying them to /col/
    for infile in $(rastercoladdborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-addborder/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile: $$infile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
        printf "\tconvert $$infile -bordercolor \"rgb(234,241,246)\" -border 10x10 $$outfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done; \
    printf "allcoladdborder: " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)
    for infile in $(rastercoladdborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-addborder/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    printf "\n\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

    # create the grayscale images from the color images
    for infile in $(rastercoladdborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-addborder/bw/'`; \
        colfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-addborder/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile: $$colfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
        printf "\tconvert $$colfile -colorspace Gray -level -15%%,100%% $$outfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    for infile in $(rastercolnoborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-noborder/bw/'`; \
        colfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-noborder/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile: $$colfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
        printf "\tconvert $$colfile -colorspace Gray -level -15%%,100%% $$outfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    for infile in $(rastercolrenewfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-renew/bw/'`; \
        colfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-renew/col/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile: $$colfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
        printf "\tconvert $$colfile -colorspace Gray -level -15%%,100%% $$outfile\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    printf "allbw: " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)
    for infile in $(rastercoladdborderfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-addborder/bw/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
     done
     for infile in $(rastercolnoborderfiles); \
     do \
      outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-noborder/bw/'`; \
      printf "$$outfile " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    for infile in $(rastercolrenewfiles); \
    do \
        outfile=`echo $$infile | sed 's/col-renew/bw/'`; \
        printf "$$outfile " >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE); \
    done
    printf "\n\n" >> $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

rasterfiles: rastermakefile
    make -j 2 -f $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

rasterfiles-force: rastermakefile
    rm -f $(rastercolfiles)
    rm -f $(rasterbwfiles)
    make -j 2 -f $(RASTERMAKEFILE)

force: ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview

As I understand it, you want use GNU Make to do…

- `content/part?/raster/bw/*` — the ultimate goal

  - `content/part?/raster/col/*` — a staging place before conversion to grayscale

    - `content/part?/raster/col-addborder/*` — source files that need a border to be added while copying to `col`
    - `content/part?/raster/col-noborder/*` — source files to be copied to `col`
    - `content/part?/raster/col-renew/*` — source files to be copied to `col`

Therefore, I believe that the makefile needs to accomplish…

1. Enumerate source files in `content/part?/raster/{col-addborder,col-noborder,col-renew}/*` using `$(wildcard …)`.
2. Based on the results of (1), calculate the list of files that should exist in `content/part?/raster/col`, and make them if necessary.
3. Based on the results of (2), calculate the list of files that should exist in `content/part?/raster/bw`, and make them if necessary.

As you have found, generating makefiles like that, which embed the names of the files that currently exist, is a bad idea.  That's not how Make is intended to be used at all.

To get make to do everything for you, there are three features that can help:

- [Static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)
- [The `eval` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function)
- [The `call` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function)

#### Static pattern rules

These rules say: "For targets that look like *some pattern*, tweak the path like *so* to obtain the prerequisite(s).  Here's the recipe."

For example, you "want" a rule that says:

```
$(rasterbwfiles): $(imgpathN)/bw/%: $(imgpathN)/col/%
    convert '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't quite work, since `$(imgpathN)` is also varying, and static pattern rules can only have one varying part, which is the `%` placeholder.  So, we actually need five static pattern rules.

#### Strategy A: Write every rule five times in your makefile

You could write, for example:

```
$(rasterbwfiles1): $(IMGPATH1)/bw/%: $(IMGPATH1)/col/%
    convert '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'

$(rasterbwfiles2): $(IMGPATH2)/bw/%: $(IMGPATH2)/col/%
    convert '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'

$(rasterbwfiles3): $(IMGPATH3)/bw/%: $(IMGPATH3)/col/%
    convert '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'

$(rasterbwfiles4): $(IMGPATH4)/bw/%: $(IMGPATH4)/col/%
    convert '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'

$(rasterbwfiles5): $(IMGPATH5)/bw/%: $(IMGPATH5)/col/%
    convert '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'
```

… but that's inelegant.

#### Strategy B: Dynamically evaluated makefile

Instead of writing parts of the makefile five times, let Make evaluate dynamic rules, using `$(eval …)`.  To evaluate varying text, use `$(call …)` on a variable that acts like a template.

```
IMGPATH1    = content/part1/raster
IMGPATH2    = content/part2/raster
IMGPATH3    = content/part3/raster
IMGPATH4    = content/part4/raster
IMGPATH5    = content/part5/raster

IMGPATHS    = $(IMGPATH1) $(IMGPATH2) $(IMGPATH3) $(IMGPATH4) $(IMGPATH5)

CP          = cp
CONVERT     = convert

CP_RULE     = $(CP) '$<' '$@'
BORDER_RULE = $(CONVERT) '$<' -bordercolor "rgb(234,241,246)" -border 10x10 '$@'
GRAY_RULE   = $(CONVERT) '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'

######################################################################

define defs_template
rastercoladdborderfiles_$(1)        := $$(wildcard $(1)/col-addborder/*)
rastercolfiles_from_addborder_$(1)  := $$(subst /col-addborder/,/col/,$$(rastercoladdborderfiles_$(1)))

rastercolnoborderfiles_$(1)         := $$(wildcard $(1)/col-noborder/*)
rastercolfiles_from_noborder_$(1)   := $$(subst /col-noborder/,/col/,$$(rastercolnoborderfiles_$(1)))

rastercolrenewfiles_$(1)            := $$(wildcard $(1)/col-renew/*)
rastercolfiles_from_renew_$(1)      := $$(subst /col-renew/,/col/,$$(rastercolrenewfiles_$(1)))

rastercolfiles_$(1)                 := $$(sort $$(rastercolfiles_from_addborder_$(1)) \
                                               $$(rastercolfiles_from_noborder_$(1)) \
                                               $$(rastercolfiles_from_renew_$(1)))

rasterbwfiles_$(1)                  := $$(subst /col/,/bw/,$$(rastercolfiles_$(1)))
endef

######################################################################

define rules_template
$$(rastercolfiles_from_addborder_$(1)): $(1)/col/%: $(1)/col-addborder/%
     $$(BORDER_RULE)

$$(rastercolfiles_from_noborder_$(1)): $(1)/col/%: $(1)/col-noborder/%
     $$(CP_RULE)

$$(rastercolfiles_from_renew_$(1)): $(1)/col/%: $(1)/col-renew/%
     $$(CP_RULE)

$$(rasterbwfiles_$(1)): $(1)/bw/%: $(1)/col/%
     $$(GRAY_RULE)
endef

######################################################################

$(foreach imgpath,$(IMGPATHS),$(eval $(call defs_template,$(imgpath))))

rastercolfiles := $(foreach imgpath,$(IMGPATHS),$(rastercolfiles_$(imgpath)))
rasterbwfiles  := $(foreach imgpath,$(IMGPATHS),$(rasterbwfiles_$(imgpath)))

all: $(rasterbwfiles)

.PHONY: all

$(foreach imgpath,$(IMGPATHS),$(eval $(call rules_template,$(imgpath))))
```

Some remarks:

- The `all` target should be [`.PHONY`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets), since you're not actually creating a file named `all`.  You had several other phony targets as well, which I haven't bothered to reproduce above.
- (Re-)making the `bw` files will automatically (re-)make the `col` files.
- It's considered good style to specify your [recipes using variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Command-Variables) rather than hard-coding them.
- The `all` rule definition has to come before all other rule definitions.  However, it has to come after your variable definitions, since some of them are [simply expanded variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).

As elegant as Strategy B may be, I don't fully recommend it, because dynamic makefiles are hard to write and debug.

#### Strategy C: Five makefiles

Instead, I suggest treating your five `$(IMGPATHS)` as five "projects", each with its own makefile.  It just happens that all five makefiles will be identical.  You can symlink them all to a canonical copy of that makefile, or you can write five makefiles that consist solely of an [`include ../../../Common.mak`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) directive.

The common makefile feels more natural than the templated version above.

```
CP          = cp
CONVERT     = convert

CP_RULE     = $(CP) '$<' '$@'
BORDER_RULE = $(CONVERT) '$<' -bordercolor "rgb(234,241,246)" -border 10x10 '$@'
GRAY_RULE   = $(CONVERT) '$<' -colorspace Gray -level -15%,100% '$@'

######################################################################

rastercoladdborderfiles        := $(wildcard col-addborder/*)
rastercolfiles_from_addborder  := $(rastercoladdborderfiles:col-addborder/%=col/%)

rastercolnoborderfiles         := $(wildcard col-noborder/*)
rastercolfiles_from_noborder   := $(rastercolnoborderfiles:col-noborder/%=col/%)

rastercolrenewfiles            := $(wildcard col-renew/*)
rastercolfiles_from_renew      := $(rastercolrenewfiles:col-renew/%=col/%)

rastercolfiles                 := $(sort $(rastercolfiles_from_addborder) \
                                         $(rastercolfiles_from_noborder) \
                                         $(rastercolfiles_from_renew))

rasterbwfiles                  := $(rastercolfiles:col/%=bw/%)

######################################################################

all: $(rasterbwfiles)

.PHONY: all

######################################################################

$(rastercolfiles_from_addborder): col/%: col-addborder/%
    $(BORDER_RULE)

$(rastercolfiles_from_noborder): col/%: col-noborder/%
    $(CP_RULE)

$(rastercolfiles_from_renew): col/%: col-renew/%
    $(CP_RULE)

$(rasterbwfiles): bw/%: col/%
    $(GRAY_RULE)
```

Then, you'd have a top-level makefile that [calls Make recursively](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion).

```
IMGPATH1     = content/part1/raster
IMGPATH2     = content/part2/raster
IMGPATH3     = content/part3/raster
IMGPATH4     = content/part4/raster
IMGPATH5     = content/part5/raster

IMGPATHS     = $(IMGPATH1) $(IMGPATH2) $(IMGPATH3) $(IMGPATH4) $(IMGPATH5)

TARGETS      = all
RECURSE_RULE = $(foreach imgpath,$(IMGPATHS),$(MAKE) -C $(imgpath) $@; )

$(TARGETS):
    $(RECURSE_RULE)

.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
```

In summary, I think that this is the best way to get around the limitation that static pattern rules can only have on varying part.  It works, because the five projects have a parallel structure, and each project can be remade independently of the others.

Comment: Wow. Just ... wow. It'll take some time to digest all of this, but - what an incredibly well-written review. Thank you very much.

Comment: I had to change the substitution rules in the makefiles a bit to make it work (from `$(rastercoladdborderfiles:col-addborder/%:col/%)` to `$(rastercoladdborderfiles:col-addborder/%=col/%)`). Now I'm stuck with the top-level makefile. During the recursion, it apparently tries to assemble one huge command line `make -C p1 all make -C p2 all make -C p3 all ...` - is it possible that there's still some problem with the `foreach` statement?

Comment: Oops, try Rev 6. (Thanks for your edit, by the way.)